# How to wrap span around every text part in an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, word-wrap

I want to wrap a span element around each text part which is not already wrapped by another element.

I have this:

```html
<p>
  text text text text text text text text <span class="f1">f1 text</span> text text text text text text text text text text text text text <span class="f2">f2 text</span> text text text text text text text
</p>
```

What I want:

```html
<p>
  <span>text text text text text text text text</span><span class="f1">f1 text</span>
  <span>text text text text text text text text text text text text text</span><span class="f2">f2 text</span><span> text text text text text text text</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter out everything but the text nodes, and wrap them

```
$('p').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap('<span />');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/389ptwgj/)